# Select recyclerview item and blur background on Android long press?

Tags: android

Looking to do something similar to what iOS does with Android. I'd like to focus on an element in a recyclerview and blur the background on long press.

I'd like to avoid creating a whole new view that cuts around the recyclerview item or anything too hacky, but maybe that's the only way.

Any advice? Here is an iOS example:
[image: Long press highlights]

Haven't tried much yet. I could technically find the x,y positioning and create a fake view with a contextual menu on top of a blurred layout.